# Filtering output using "Where-Object" in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get into PowerShell and have encountered my first hurdle.

when I run

```
Get-Command | Where-Object CommandType -contains Cmdlet
```

My output gets filtered so that only commands with "CommandType" property value containing "Cmdlet" gets shown, like so:

[image]

Same thing can be done with the object "Source":

```
Get-Command | Where-Object Source -contains appx
```

Which gets me:

[image]

But when i try to run:

```
Get-Command | Where-Object Name -contains Add
```

I get nothing.
Why can I filter the output by the objects "CommandType", and "Source but not "Name"? I'm surely missing something here...

Edit: i know i can run:

```
Get-Command -verb "get"
```

And get the desired output. But i'm trying to figure out why my "where-object" statement did not work.

Edit 2:

Appearantly if I use the "-match" comparison operator it works...

```
get-command | where-object Name -match "add"
```

But isn't "name" properties just strings? -match should be used for Regular expression comparison afaik? I'm so confused right now...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use either the `like` or the `match` operator:

```
Get-Command | Where-Object Name -like Add*
```

this will match add anywhere in the word

```
Get-Command | Where-Object Name -match Add
```

but a better way to do this would be:

```
Get-Command -verb Add
```

read more about the contains operator [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx)

-Contains
      Description: Containment operator. Tells whether a collection of reference
      values includes a single test value. Always returns a Boolean value. Returns TRUE
      only when the test value exactly matches at least one of the reference values.

```
      PS C:\> "abc", "def" -Contains "def"
      True
```

Comment: Oh, I see now... -contains only returns true if the exact value is contained in a group of objects. I thought each individual object was parsed for an inline match. Thanks.

Comment: right...`name` property returns a single string which is passed to where and must be exactly equal to the string being compared to