# Oledb SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: c#, sql-server, oledb

I am trying to access SQL Server 2019 with `System.Data.OleDB` but I get this error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

However, I am able to connect via `SqlConnection`.

What am I missing?

Any other configuration needed for OleDb connection to work?

I have tested using both UserID and password as well as integrated security.

I am testing in own laptop/home wifi and accessing local database, also enable tcp port 1433 specifically in window firewall.

This is my code:

```
 var connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User ID=sa;Password=sa"

 //var connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI"

 OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

 using (connection)
 {
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from TestTable", connection);
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     da.Fill(ds);
}
```

Comment: [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection)

Comment: @Jimi as mentioned i can connect via SqlConnection but not OleDB, but I would need to connect to sql server with OleDB for this project as per requirement. I am looking for solution on how to make OleDB work with SQL Server

Comment: You miss out open the connection. Add [`connection.Open();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.open?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-data-oledb-oledbconnection-open) before the line `OleDbCommand cmd = ...;` line.

Comment: @YongShun I have tested your suggestion, it still give same error message. And why would I need to specifically call connection.Open() in code since I already wrap with using()

Comment: Wrap with `using()` is for `IDisposable` to perform `Dispose()` the connection automatically when it ends. But it wouldn't help to open the connection automatically. For your reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: Too short. It was about what's in the Remarks section. Which will lead to `SqlConnection.ConnectionString` and the Connection builder. See `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` @Yong Shun The DataAdapter opens the connection on its own if it's closed. The using block is unrelated. Shouldn't be written like that, though.

Comment: @YongShun a DataAdapter knows how to open a connection itself; it actually has a very specific behavior in that regard - if given an open connection, it leaves it open (transaction enrolment purposes), and if given a closed connection it opens/closes it

Comment: Thanks Jimi & Carius for the `DataAdapter` knowledge. (Markdown on the notebook). And sorry stackdisplay for the incorrect info provided.

Comment: Can this help you? https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/

Comment: The code should work provided you have the credentials to access the database.  The database (mdf file) has to be attached to the database for the code to work.  So I usually recommend using SQL Server Management Studio to help solve issue.  The login screen has two options 1) Windows Credentials (integrated security = true) 2)SQL Credentials (username and password).  Try both.  Also try doing the same query as posted with SSMS.  You can check the credentials of the database using SSMS going to the security tab.  Make sure database is attached.

Comment: Besides that, you can use [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) as reference. See, e.g., [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/)

Comment: Nice, helpful error message - the server might not exist, or maybe you got the credentials wrong. /eyeroll. Assuming that it's connecting to the SQL Server instance successfully check the instance's Error Log for 18456 authentication failure events, take note of the State numbers in them, and compare against the State numbers at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error) to figure out the failure mode.

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to connect to SQL Server using [System.Data.OleDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netframework-4.8).

According to [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Different generations of OLE DB Drivers:
>
> There are three distinct generations of Microsoft OLE DB providers for
> SQL Server.
>
> 1. Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (SQLOLEDB) The Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (SQLOLEDB) still ships as part of
>    Windows Data Access Components. It is not maintained anymore and it is
>    not recommended to use this driver for new development.
> 2. SQL Server Native Client (SNAC) Starting in SQL Server 2005 (9.x), the SQL Server Native Client (SNAC) includes an OLE DB provider
>    interface (SQLNCLI) and is the OLE DB provider that shipped with SQL
>    Server 2005 (9.x) through SQL Server 2012 (11.x).
>
> It was announced as deprecated in 2011 and it is not recommended to
> use this driver for new development. For more information about the
> SNAC lifecycle and available downloads, refer to SNAC lifecycle
> explained.
>
> 3. Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (MSOLEDBSQL) OLE DB was undeprecated and released in 2018.
>
> **The new OLE DB provider is called the Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL
> Server (MSOLEDBSQL).** The new provider will be updated with the most
> recent server features going forward.
>
> Note:
>
> To use the new Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server in existing
> applications, you should plan to convert your connection strings from
> SQLOLEDB or SQLNCLI, to MSOLEDBSQL.

One can find the connection string [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/).

Before proceeding, it's necessary to identify the server name where SQL Server is installed, and the instance name (if one exists).

**To find the server name**:

- Open a cmd window, and type: `hostname`

**To find the SQL Server instance name**:

**Option 1**:

- Open a cmd window, and type:

```
sc query | find /i "SQL Server"
```

You'll see something like the following: `DISPLAY_NAME: SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`. The SQL Server instance name is within (). In this case, the SQL Server instance name is: `SQLEXPRESS`

**Option 2**

- Open PowerShell, and run the following:

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Microsoft\SqlServer  -Query "Select Name from __Namespace where Name like 'ComputerManagement%'" | ForEach-Object { $sqlMgmtVer = $_.Name; Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Microsoft\SqlServer\$sqlMgmtVer -Class FileStreamSettings |Select-Object InstanceName }
```

**Option 3**

- Open PowerShell, and run the following:

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\cimv2  -Query "Select DisplayName from Win32_Service where DisplayName like 'SQL Server%'" | ForEach-Object {$dName = $_.DisplayName; if ($dName -match "^SQL Server \((?<instanceName>.*)\)$") { $matches["instanceName"]; }}
```

Now that we've gathered the necessary information, try the following:

```
// '.' can be used instead of "localhost" or "127.0.0.1"
// SQL Server instance name = SQLExpress
private string _connectionStr = @"Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=TestDB;UID=test;PWD=mySecretPassword;";

public DataTable GetProductInfo()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(_connectionStr))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Product", con))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Connection Strings - SQL Server OLE DB](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/)
- [System.Data.OleDb Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Filtering output using "Where-Object" in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35334233/filtering-output-using-where-object-in-powershell)
- [Windows PowerShell: Extracting Strings Using Regular Expressions](https://techtalk.gfi.com/windows-powershell-extracting-strings-using-regular-expressions/)
- [Powershell: The many ways to use regex](https://powershellexplained.com/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/#named-matches)
- [Chapter 7 - Working with WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/07-working-with-wmi?view=powershell-7.2)