# Provider : SQL Network Interfaces, Error: 26 - Error Locating Server/ Instance specified

Tags: c#, sql-server

What does this exception error mean?

> A network related or instance specific error occured while establishing a connection to sql server. The server was not found or was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
> (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error locating Server/ Instance specified)

I have a contract management system project and I already deploy it. But when I run my project on another PC, I get this error.

How can that be?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, I googled but I can't find anything.

Comment: The important part is _error: 26 - Error locating Server/ Instance specified_. This usually means that the SQL Browser service cannot be contacted on UDP port 1434. When you specify an Instance Name in your connection string the client tries to communicate with the SQL Browser service using the SQL Server Resolution Protocol to convert the instance name into the TCP port number that the particular instance is listening on. The client then attempts to connect to the instance using that TCP port. If you know which port your instance is listening on use `Server=ServerNameOrIpAddress,PortNumber;`

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198996/cant-access-my-sql-server-via-c-sharp-form-application-from-client-device/71199793#71199793 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71183112/oledb-sql-server-does-not-exist-or-access-denied/71187302#71187302